# Posts not showing on my website Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I had an issue with posts. I have installed the elementor pluggin, when I edit my page I can see al the blog content as I'm editing it, but when I search the post in my website It doesn't show the text content. I tried changing the settings -> reading -> post page but it didn't work.